# What should you do when eye contact makes your subordinate uncomfortable?

Tags: communication, united-states

I am a newly promoted engineering supervisor, with a team of four engineers reporting to me. I have worked with them for several years before being promoted and we have a great, friendly dynamic. That has not changed, but what has changed is that I now have 1-on-1 meetings with them to discuss their tasks and performance (all great, no hard conversations). In these meetings, we sit across from each other and talk.

Two of my engineers are clearly uncomfortable in this set up, unable to maintain eye contact and so look around the room as they talk most of the time. It doesn’t bother me that they are looking around, but I don’t know what to do myself in this situation. I want my employees to be comfortable and able to talk openly to me. They don’t interact with customers so I have no need to change them, and they are both excellent at their jobs.

My natural response is to just keep looking at them and smiling, but I worry this is not helpful. Looking away myself feels dismissive. I am hoping someone who doesn’t like eye contact can offer me some tips!

I’m asking what I can do body language wise to reduce their nervousness. The relationships are good, we just never had conversations like this before as peers (one on one, task-focused) and so I don’t have any experience to inform me.

**Does me keeping looking at them make it worse? Should I try to look away more? Should I try to ditch the sitting across from each other and try sitting on the same side of a table?**

Second Edit: Thank you so much, everyone! I’ll add a couple of things for further clarification, but I have great ideas for improvements thanks to y’all.

Intimidation is not a significant factor - I came in as the ‘lead’, formed the good relationship I reference, was the only one who went for the promotion — I was the obvious choice, and there were no hard feelings. It was a very seamless transition. I imagine there are some nerves present as we move through this transition, but I generally think it’s more about who they are as people (some don’t like eye contact!).

One is male and another one is female, so it is not obviously gendered. There are two other engineers who make an ‘expected’ amount of eye contact, so these two I am discussing are a contrast in their lower amount in the same situation. They do make eye contact with me at intervals, I just think they, as people, don’t like eye contact very much. If just not messing with them is sufficient, wonderful! That’s what I’m hearing.

I don’t know they are uncomfortable necessarily, more like, I, a social person, have not encountered this situation and myself am uncomfortable. Based on input, they don’t care what I do really, which is a relief!

Comment: Do you bring anything with you to meetings, things you might have to glance at every so often? Like a notepad for example.

Comment: Do you think they have developed an inferiority-complex? Because, not long ago you were working with them as a colleague (same level, I assume), and now you have been promoted as a Supervisor?

Comment: Did you notice this behavior also before becoming their superior? Were they avoiding eye contact when you were also peers, when discussing tasks at your desks or when you meet them for lunch?

Comment: What country/culture is this? You may want to tag your question appropriately. In some countries looking directly in the eyes of a (formally) superior person would be considered disrespectful by at least one of the persons.

Comment: Did you try sitting on the same side of the table?

Comment: Is it possible to have these meetings over phone?

Comment: **"Two of my engineers are clearly uncomfortable in this set up, unable to maintain eye contact and so look around the room as they talk most of the time."** *Are* they actually uncomfortable? I don't always maintain a lot of eye contact, and as long as the person I'm talking with doesn't mind that, the fact that I'm *not* maintaining eye contact lets me *remain* comfortable.  What *would* be uncomfortable is if I had to try to maintain eye contact. Are you asking them to do that?

Comment: As someone who has trouble maintaining eye contact in a meeting like this, it's a mix of being concerned that the person I'm talking to doesn't like that I move my eyes around and not noticing what they do with theirs.

Comment: So you are only able to communicate at best when adding eye contact, facial expression and body language to your message? (I like to switch perspective when ppl start using "unable" and terms like that; as if eyes, face and body language are mandatory - they are only mandatory to that kind of ppl)

Comment: "One is male and another one is female, so it is not obviously gendered." Not so obvious.  Even ignoring a potential impact from homosexuality/bi-sexuality, it could be that one person has a mental issue; the other might not have the same mental issue, and this could easily be a gender-based issue for one of them.  Don't be thinking that both people will necessarily have the same root cause.

Comment: @TOOGAM: did you confuse "it is not obviously gendered" with "it is obviously not gendered"?

Comment: I did read it that way.  Cursed be some of English's ambiguity.  My point still remains.

Answer (score 262):

Go take a walk around the block while you two talk. That's what we do here and it works pretty well.

Comment: Have to upvote this - takes out the "pressure" of a room etc etc

Comment: Signed up to upvote. Gets people out of their chairs as well, which has its own benefits.

Comment: This is a great answer. When people are uncomfortable in a situation and you don't want to change them, don't try to 'fix' the problem, just change the situation so the problem disappears.

Comment: @SolarMike Most importantly you don't have people facing each other but walking by each other's side. There's no awkward looking around because you don't have to balance between looking at someone too much and too little. You just look ahead while occasionally looking at the other person.

Comment: @user31389 So many words to put across what I did...

Comment: No, you were talking about "pressure" of a room which is an entirely different thing. The room is not at fault but the fact that some people feel awkward facing other people. You could have people seated side by side in a room and it would likely work just as well as a walk. And most likely there's no "pressure" at fault. It's not the perception of high expectations or seriousness that causes people to avoid eye contact. They are just a bit socially awkward, that's all.

Comment: I've seen this a couple times now, and it really is a neat way to get quick 1-on-1 meetings without the tension inherent in sitting down in a little room together.

Comment: I've never had any 1-1 meetings in person (I work freelance). Wouldn't you need a computer to refer to tasks you're working on, take notes, etc.? If so that would be quite difficult while walking...

Comment: @ChrisCirefice the 1-on-1 here sounds more like personal "how is it going, are you enjoying your work, how can we help each other better" talks.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice if a computer is needed then noone has to make eye-contact anyway, since you can both be looking at the computer

Comment: @ChrisCirefice a notepad may be a good idea - stop for a few seconds to write something down if it comes up. Or a phone to set a calendar reminder/to-do item

Comment: This might work sometimes, but I'm not sure OP has given enough details to make clear this is the right fix. As such, I'm `-1`ing because you can't readily take notes like this. Especially in engineering disciplines, details are important and failing to record them immediately (before forgetting little bits) can have consequences.

Comment: 1-on-1s don't have to be super formal. If one needs to take notes, take a walk to a nearby coffee shop. Or say, "Let me write that down so I don't forget it" and add it in a notebook. You should be doing that in 1-on-1s *anyway*, so...

Answer (score 216):

**I'm one of those people**

I believe you are reading too much into this!

Don't start with team-building exercises, surveys, etc. Leave it be.

If you are getting the results you need from these sessions, that's what matters.

Some people just naturally don't like eye contact in one-on-one conversations. Me included! That includes me being in positions of power or otherwise.

Look wherever you want.  The important thing is you listen and respond.

Comment: I was about to answer exactly the same. People are just introverts or don't like eye contact. People going overboard methinks.

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear - I don’t care they don’t want to look at me, I just want to know what I can do to take the social pressure off them more. Sitting face to face and keeping looking at them while they look away doesn’t seem like the best option, but I don’t know what the other options are!

Comment: If we aren't looking at you, we don't know where you're looking :) Do whatever you want. Dance if you want.

Comment: I agree with this. Simple enough. To me, it feels like overthinking. If everything is good there's absolutely no reason to change things.

Comment: @user35316 as someone else who also feels uncomfortable with eye contact, please understand that "taking the social pressure off" won't solve the problem, because it is not necessarily a problem! Don't take a lack of eye contact as meaning they feel uncomfortable. It's entirely possible that encouraging them to make eye contact will just make them more uncomfortable -- if they even are.

Comment: +1. How does the OP _know_ they are making their employees uncomfortable or putting pressure on them?

Comment: There are also cultures in which "eye contact" can be considered extremely rude.

Comment: @user35316, I know I do this too, and it has nothing to do with social pressure or discomfort. I just simply have a hard time maintaining eye contact while thinking about the answer to whatever question you just asked me. If I'm thinking about looking at your eyes, I'm not thinking about the conversation we're having. It's just not how my brain works.

Comment: I also avoid constant eye contact with people. I don't think OP should assume any social pressure. I'm not shy, anxious, or particularly introverted. I just find it weird to stare down the person I'm speaking to. Not to mention there are other interesting things to look at than your chin. So I look around.

Comment: @SethR THIS!  I keep seeing people say they're "uncomfortable" -- I've never been uncomfortable with it, but for whatever reason maintaining eye contact prevents my brain from processing conversations properly.  Glad I'm not alone there!

Comment: I am one of those people, too ... I have been diagnosed with Aspergers, and I know that difficulty of keeping eye contact is one of the diagnosing criteria. And I need to constantly remind myself that "normal" people expect eye contact in conversation -- but that takes concentration away from the dialog and/or the problem at hand. As a consequence, if I maintain eye contact, I feel social pressure to do it. If I don't maintain eye contact, it actually means that I feel comfortable enough with the dialog partner to ignore that social pressure. So I agree with this answer: Leave it be.

Comment: I was one of those too . It's important for us to learn to interact better with society. I learned a few tricks to blend in better like you don't actually have to look them in the eye , but count freckles or look at their teeth .

Answer (score 57):

I've been in similar situations where people were unable to look me in the eye whilst in a 1-1 meeting. It was pretty clear that they weren't feeling inferior but rather socially awkward/anxious and slightly introvert.

I tried different things and what seemed to work well was sitting next to the person instead of across from them during 1-1s and use a laptop or notes between us to focus on. Most of the time I was focused on the screen while talking and that gave the opportunity to the other person to talk while looking at the screen or notes.

If you're happy with the meetings' outcome and you're able to communicate fine with your subordinates, then I'd simply try to find a layout for these meetings that makes them more comfortable.

Comment: Was going to suggest this if no one else had. Most men are socialized to interact side by side or around an activity and not face-to-face, since face-to-face means head-to-head which is combative.

Comment: Don't assume all men are combative.

Comment: Nobody discussing the "spectrum" yet?  They are engineers after all. Eye contact is pretty intrusive. Insisting upon it can open up a world of problems. Some people just don't.

Comment: Looking at notes or doing sth else while talking is a sign of lack of interest. Thats not really a wanted impression on others

Comment: Upvoted @Jannis. As a very technical engineer type, I think eye contact has little value. Show me proof, calculations or results. The rest is just fluff for those that need it (girls?)

Comment: Sitting side by side may just worsen the problem. Why not just ditch the concept of eyes, face and body being a requirement in communication - because, they are not. It's just the people like you who seem to _need_ these actually unecessary things. Introverts, aspies and the like have the ability to get along without all those energy wasters.

Comment: @Jannis I'm in the "dislikes eye contact" camp. I have regular one on ones where my superior is sitting across from (or next to) me looking at a laptop, and I remain comfortable and get no impression of a lack of interest.

Comment: @chiliNUT I really think too that eye contact has no value. Still I was taught to look people in the eye, when talking to them. I guess everyone has preferences

Comment: @Jannis fair enough! I was taught that too. I used to try to always do it, discovered I was not a fan, and now I feel out the situation and may maintain eye contact on occasion if it feels right, but I don't do it as a rule.

Answer (score 30):

Something that hasn't been mentioned is that they may be **thinking.**

When you ask me a technical question, I mentally fire up the equipment and software I'd use to work on the problem for real and then run through possible solutions or approaches.

I'm mentally looking at things that are somewhere else.  My eyes just rove and have very little to do with what I'm looking at.

I might "park" my peepers staring at blank section of wall or out a window.  If I'm really far away, they just stop wherever they were pointed - which may be at you or someone else, causing creepy feelings of "why's he staring at me?"

So, if you are having a one on one discussion and your coworker is staring off into space, he may be really busy trying to find a solution.  Anything you do to prevent them from "spacing out" might cause you to lose out on a better solution to your problems.

Comment: I do this too, looking off into space while I think about my answer, but when I'm done thinking I cycle back to eye contact, at least momentarily. The OP didn't mention if the cycling back ever happens or not.

Comment: Was going to post a similar answer. I find that having [ADHD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_deficit_hyperactivity_disorder) means I often cannot focus on both the discussion _and_ the environment (including the person) at the same time. This means, if I'm making eye contact during a conversation, it's highly likely I'm not paying nearly the same amount of attention to the object of the discussion. It has nothing to do with being uncomfortable in my case. I noticed Elon Musk does that a lot, too.

Comment: Most people move their eyes while they're thinking. That's just what we do. I'm not sure if there are statistically significant directions that we glance while thinking, but I've heard there are.

Answer (score 15):

The individuals in question could be on the autism spectrum such Asperger's Syndrome which is high functioning autism . Such individuals have difficulty with eye contact and are uncomfortable in social situations. This is offset by intense focus on a field of study that they become extremely good at what they do. As for body language I have noticed that they have a hard time correctly interpreting it. You mentioned that one is male and one is female. Asperger's manifests itself differently in men and women.

Comment: This answer should be the right one. Being diagnosed with Aspergers myself, I found myself in the OP's description right from the start. And my best advice to the OP is (assuming they really are on the autism spectrum): Don't change your behaviour, just leave it be. If they ignore the social pressure to keep eye contact, it means they are already as comfortable with you as they can be. Changing your behaviour just reduces their comfort because they will notice that and need to interpret your new behaviour.

Comment: Also, yes, many of us autists do have a hard time interpreting the body language of non-autists. In addition, we have a very hard time when trying to "read between the lines". It gets way easier when dealing with other autists, though.

Comment: I find a pint or two usually fixes it :)

Comment: I am an engineer and I think I fall somewhat into this category. Since high school, I've commonly been told by friends, in disbelief when a girl was "totally flirting" .. and I apparently just blew her off .. and every time I would have absolutely no idea that, that's what was going on.

Comment: @orithena As the neural -typicals might say " It takes one to know one". I was diagnosed as an adult with A.S shortly after my son was diagnosed with it as a child.

Comment: @MikeM That explains a lot in my own life as well. A woman's body language is far more subtle than a man's. I knew a woman for 30 years and had no idea that she was into me....until one Christmas Eve..she finally figured out subtlety wasn't working.

Answer (score 8):

I myself find that I can listen better if I'm not making an effort to maintain eye contact. After all, you listen with your ears, not your eyes. Because of this, my own eyes tend to wander during conversation, whether I'm any kind of nervous or not.

It may be the same for these individuals. You don't know, so don't make assumptions. If they are performing well and can remember what was discussed, it doesn't really matter that they don't maintain eye contact with you, and no additional action is needed.

Comment: “You listen with your ears, not your eyes.” This is just straight up wrong. There have been studies that have shown that something like 90% of communication is nonverbal. If you want to do a good job as a listener, you need to use both.

Comment: @nick012000 that's a very oft misquoted study, and the real amount is much lower, and much of it is tone of voice, which you pick up with your ears as well.

Comment: @nick012000 And we're not talking about conversations with emotional subtexts, necessarily.  These are very likely pretty technical conversations, so body language plays much less of a role.

Comment: @nick012000 To be fair, I don't have to maintain eye contact to read body language, and I have become very good at reading slight nuances in the other's voice. And I promise that if I could see my conversation partner but not hear them, I definitely would not pick up 90% of their meaning.

Answer (score 4):

You mention:

> In these meetings we sit across from each other and talk.

Why do you sit across each other? Just write down the things you want to talk about, and say to that person that you want to discuss the points you have written down. The best way to do this is to sit **next to** each other. While sitting like that, both of you look at the paper and there's no need anymore for having eye-contact.

Comment: The downvote is not mine, but you don't need the paper. In terms of body language, sitting across is really not optimal, since it is confrontational. However, sitting next to each other is not optimal either and the paper is defenitely distracting from the conversation. A good option would be to do without the paper and sit perpendicular, which is a good seating order in a cooperative setup. If you change your answer in that direction, you have my upvote.

Comment: that's right. Sitting accros eachother is confrontational....sitting NEXT to each other is the easiest solution here!

Comment: I agree with you, opposite each other may be uncomfortable. I usually sit in a 90 degree angle, when sitting next to each other may be too familiar. That way you're close without crossing eyes all the time.

Comment: @reinierpost: Tha's what I meant with *perpendicular*: a 90° angle...

Answer (score 2):

> Does me keeping looking at them make it worse?

Not directly (see below).

> Should I try to look away more? Should I try to ditch the sitting across from each other and try sitting on the same side of a table?

No need. It's not you looking at them that's the problem, it's their discomfort looking at you.

There is *potentially* an added discomfort imbued by the expectation that when someone looks at you, you look back (so the coworker may feel an element of "obligation" that they cannot fulfil, causing further discomfort).

But, in my personal experience, I wouldn't worry too much about *your* approach here, as long as you're not actively rebuking them for not giving eye contact back (which would suck because, for some people, it's genuinely *really, really hard*).

That being said, there are some excellent suggestions in other answers (e.g. having a "walking meeting") that nix the entire problem at source; that way you can eliminate any issue at all, provided these ideas fit in well with your workflow and daily structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been working with them for a long time and have now become their "superior" this is common to happen. They may have the problem of trying to separate the relationship they used to have with the one they have now.

There are a few things you can try.

1. Just give them the room they need, if their performance is not lacking and motivation seems to be the same, leave it as it is. Continue looking at them while they speak and remain professional.
2. If you have worked with them for that long and feel the relationship exists there, ask them. While you are on the 1-on-1 tell them you have noticed that they don't seem to be fully comfortable and ask them if they prefer a different approach to the 1-on-1.
3. Use an anonymous survey to the entire team regarding current processes, including 1-on-1, PDP and PDR.

As you said, they are not going to be customer facing, but it is also good to give them the opportunity to develop their interpersonal skills.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote on this one. This seems pretty valid.

Comment: @GustavoMP I'm not the downvoter but the general trend in low score answers to this question is that they assume there's something wrong, the employees are nervous, etc. The truth is some people simply are uncomfortable looking other people in the eyes in any kind of situation or don't know where they are supposed to look or think looking at other person too long would be considered rude. There is nothing wrong with the workplace nor the supervisor.

Comment: @user31389 with that I can agree

Answer (score 1):

Others have contributed some good thoughts. Some personal perspective:

1. What sort of training has your employer provided for those new to management? Do they provide skill building materials?
2. Social skills are a bit less relevant if the job isn't customer facing.
3. Try not to judge employee on looking in eye,  but more on whatever their positive qualities are, and your assessment of their contributions.
4. Do not make assumptions on character, rush to judgement, or over-simplify based on a few observations.
5. Don't discuss with other managers at your level.  Not necessarily their business...
6. You do have a mentor responsibility, so think about what that entails and whether social skills are relevant.
   6.a. I've done customer facing work,  and not always handled it the best. In that case I was fortunate to have a manager that could skillfully address it, and identify areas to improve, and highlight good parts (so I'm not demoralized). Keep in mind I was hired partially due to better social skills.
   6.b. The other side,  purely internally focused work. Just keep in mind everyone is not created equal and some people will *not* be able to "improve" their social skills. That's OK.  Then focus more on whether tasks are getting done,  quality of work, etc.

Comment: I would agree with everything but #5. You can discuss with other managers as they are now your peer group, and would likely have valuable feedback/suggestions. You can avoid talking about specific people, but overall, it's fine to speak with people at your level.

I do think that it is *better* to speak with colleagues outside of the company, or if you have a mentor, speak with them.

Comment: Thanks, Sounds like a better take on what I wrote. I would worry a new manager might share too much with peers.

Answer (score 0):

In America, it's common for companies to do "team-building" exercises.   They usually consist of the team going to lunch, or having a gathering off site with families, even.  It's to allow people get to know each other in casual situations, and this can help with a person viewing their boss/manager as a person, not just an authority to be scared of.

Perhaps this isn't an option, but for whatever reason they seem to fear you.   Might just be a cultural thing...but you need to try to find a way to break through that.

Comment: Doesn't seem like they fear him from what he said.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some good examples of things you can do to get around this uncomfortable feeling mentioned by others.

The main thing here should be to build your coworkers confidence (restless eyes are caused by nerves and lack of confidence) rather than find more ways they can avoid eye contact. Eye contact is a very important skill and should not be overlooked as it's the main way to connect during conversation. It's not something that should be avoided no matter who you are.

That being said

> (all great, no hard conversations)

They might not be uncomfortable but just nervous during these 121's. You get what you need and conversation is still flowing. If colleagues were uncomfortable there would likely be rushed speech or stutters along with lack of eye contact

Comment: There are many cultures that do not view "Eye Contact" as an important business or professional skill. For example, I work with Japanese partners where the business culture in meetings is to look down and "listen" with perhaps the exception of the person being directly addressed, even closing eyes is considered normal, and it took me a while to get used to speaking at meetings and to trust that they are listening intently even if they look like they are sleeping (although, sometimes they are).

Comment: "Restless eyes are caused by nerves and lack of confidence" that is not true for me. I have a hard time looking people in the eye, but I would definitely not be categorized as someone lacking confidence or having nerves. I simply don't like to. It's never caused me any problems in business, in fact, i think it has helped, because too much eye contact can be seen as rude and aggressive where I am (pnw in the US)

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been answered already, I am trying to include my 2 cents. By reading your question, you said:

> I don’t know they are uncomfortable necessarily, more like, I, a social person, have not encountered this situation and myself am uncomfortable. Based on input, they don’t care what I do really, which is a relief!

Don't judge people if they are uncomfortable. Especially during meetings some people don't make eye contact, because they stare in space to digest/understand the important points and trying to match if it relates to their questions. Usually people are uncomfortable if they don't know the answer or afraid of being asked what they have not fulfilled or done before.

So, I'd say try to make more friendly conversation with individuals by 1:1 coffee or walk. You can ask issues which are bothering them or something they can't talk during the meeting. Try to grill down to the level where they are confident to disclose if anything in their mind and assure them that will be taken care. I believe this will help maintain good healthy relations with them if you convince them. At the end of the day you're on higher position, there's always respect and little one step back bonding always there in them.

Comment: What do you mean by *"little one step back bonding always there in them"* (seemingly incomprehensible)?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who tended to avoid eye contact when younger, I also think you are giving too much importance to it.

When younger I had some personal confidence and privacy issues, which are not all related to my culture, and people actually complained I did not pay attention to them just because I did not look them right on the eye.

Actually with age, hundreds and meetings and life experience - including some failed relationships because of being shy, nowadays I interact pretty much as expected.

Just be aware this might be a learned skillset for some people.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely they are nervous.  Many employees will feel nervous talking to their manager 1 on 1.  Add the fact that you are their new manager, talking about their tasks and performance and this nervous factor can increase.  Add the fact that they are engineers, who in many cases are introverts, and you can understand how elevated their nerves must be.

There isn't anything to change on your part as far as smiling and looking at them.  What you can do, before the meeting, is try to calm them down and make it clear that the meeting isn't an official review or that they aren't being punished for anything.

Comment: I am not the person OP is talking about but I am like them, I do not do well with eye to eye contact. Nothing to do with nerves. I just do not like it. (I might be Autistic, but high functional and have not other problems.)